# Help me identify this wasp-like insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

I've never seen wasps with long legs like that.

It's not big, about 1-2cm in length (not counting legs).

Could you identify this?

UPD: location is central Ukraine

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The details of the insect are listed below:

**Common Name:** Craneflies

**Zoological Name:** Ctenophora flaveolata

**Location**(mostly found at): Eastern Europe

Here is the Biological Identification,

**Kingdom:** Animilia

**Phylum:** Arthropoda

**Class:** Insecta

**Order:** Diptera

**Family:** Tipulidae

**Genus:** Ctenophora Meigen

**Features:** The species are large (about 20 mm long, with 25-mm wingspans), shiny black craneflies with large yellow, orange, or red markings to mimic wasps. Males have comb-like antennae. The larvae are saproxylic. The species are confined to old deciduous forests, orchards, and other habitats with continuity of the presence of dying and fallen trees. Ctenophora species are important bioindicators.

Source: [Ctenophora (fly)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenophora_(fly))

Comment: This is mostly a copy from Wikipedia. You have to mention your sources when you copy stuff. On the SE network, however, it is discouraged to copy-paste anything ad verbatim as it can be plagiarism, especially when sources are not mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the source. Thanks for the comment.